# Why int array[][20]?

Tags: c++, arrays, function

In `ReadVector()` why do I have to write `int a[][20]`?  What is the purpose of `[20]`.   Why can't I write `a[][]`?

```
int a[20][20 ], n,m;

int ReadVector(int a[][20],int n,int m){
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        for (int j=0; j<m; j++){
            cout<<"a["<<i<<","<<j<<"]=";
            cin>>a[i][j];
            }

 return *a[20];`
```

Answer (score 2):

When you acces rows via `a[i]` the second dimension has to be know, to get to the right memory address, because

```
&(a[i]) = &(a[0]) + i*m*sizeof(int)
```

So when you acces an element, the offsets are calculated via:

```
&(a[i][j]) = &(a[0]) + i*m*sizeof(int) + j
```

Just consider how you would find an element at position `[i][j]` in a matrix if you were only allowed to count the elements starting from the first one...to make this work you have to know at least how many elements are there in a row.

Answer (score -1):

> Why can't I write `a[][]`?

Because `int a[][]` is the same as `int **a` (a pointer to a pointer to `char`) which is *not* the same as `int a[][20]` which is the same as `int (*a)[20]` (a pointer to a `char[20]`).

Applying the same pointer arithmetic to `int **a` results in something different then it will for `int (*a)[20]`.